# EJB3 / JPA @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, ejb

Is there an EJB or JPA annotiation that is equivalent to Spring's @Transactional ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something analogous to Springs @Transactional annotation availabe in JEE 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424289/is-there-something-analogous-to-springs-transactional-annotation-availabe-in-jee)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent EJB3 attribute is `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute`.

Just like Spring's `@Transactional` annotation, you can control the transaction 'propagation' by passing a `TransactionAttributeType` to the `TransactionAttribute` annotation, like:

```
@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Stateful
public class TransactionBean implements Transaction {
...
    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void firstMethod() {...}

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void secondMethod() {...}

    public void thirdMethod() {...}

    public void fourthMethod() {...}
}
```

Container managed transactions are described in [Part IV of the Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

Answer (score 3):

See javadoc on.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html

Namely the paragraph:
See the EJB specification for restrictions on the use of @Transactional with EJBs.

I did not find in EJB 3.2 any reference to the conditioning on this support.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html

However, I in weblogic 12.1.2 EJB 3.1 - the @Transactional attribute works on @Stateless @Local ejbs that you inject into a base class using the CDI @Inject annotation.

In any case, I would not use the @Transactional annotation for EJBs, even if all your EJBs are local and you inject them all with @Inject instead of @EJB.
I would continue to use the @TransactionAttribute with EJBs.