# TransactionRequiredException while trying to insert data into database

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, persistence, jta

I'm using JPA with JTA

Repository method that saves the bean is like:

```
    @Override
    public UserInfo insert(UserInfo userInfo) throws Exception {

        UserInfo user = entityManager.find(UserInfo.class, userInfo.getName());

        if (user != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla bla");
        }


            entityManager.persist(userInfo);
            entityManager.flush();

        return userInfo;
    }
```

Then the persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="perunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/dta</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.yyyy.model.UserInfo</class>
        ....
```

every time I try to save the bean, the flush() method throws the next exception

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(JTATransactionWrapper.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(JTATransactionWrapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
```

any suggestion is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you please specify in which environment you are running this code? Is it an application server?

Comment: Yes I'm using Weblogic as a server

Comment: You should mark the service that uses your Repository with @Transactional annotation

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk I'm using EJB so I guess there's no such annotation

Comment: @Gor I can't imagine JPA without Transactional. There should be equivalent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424289/is-there-something-analogous-to-springs-transactional-annotation-available-in-j

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk aaand just tried `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` and it doesn't work :)